# Why can't I use a member initialization list here?

Tags: c++

I just finished creating a "Point" class and was working on a "Line" class that has two Point objects (Point startpoint and Point endpoint) as data members. I created a constructor in my Line class that accepts two Point objects as arguments and had originally created it as follows:

```
Line(const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
{
    startpoint = p1;
    endpoint = p2;
}
```

Everything was fine, but then I decided I would use a member initialization list instead of assigning the members to p1 and p2 in the body, just because... But when I changed it to:

```
Line(const Point& p1, const Point& p2): startpoint(p1), endpoint(p2)
{
}
```

I get an error saying "no instance of constructor "Point::Point" matches the argument list" and didn't understand what this meant exactly.

Why doesn't the member initialization list work here?

Thanks.

edit: Sorry, I didn't know if the details of my point class was relevant or not:

// Point.h

```
class Point
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    Point();
    Point(Point& p);
    Point(double x1, double y1);
    ~Point();

    double X() const;
    double Y() const;

    void X(double newx);
    void Y(double newy);
    };
```

// Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point(): x(0), y(0)
{
}

Point::Point(Point& p)
{
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
}

Point::Point(double x1, double y1): x(x1), y(y1)
{
}

Point::~Point()
{
}

double Point::X() const
{
    return x;
}

double Point::Y() const
{
    return y;
}

void Point::X(double newx)
{
    x = newx;
}

void Point::Y(double newy)
{
    y = newy;
}
```

Comment: Showing us your point class might help

Comment: It means that something is wrong with the copy constructor of the Point class, probably.

Comment: For future reference, things that are not `const` can be implicitly cast to things that are `const`, but things that are `const` cannot be implicitly casted to things that are not, which is the problem you're having here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The member initialization depends on `Point` having a public copy constructor, since you explicitly calling `Point::Point(const Point&)`.

If that doesn't exist or is not accessible, you can't call it.  If you can't call it, it isn't because the *initialization list* doesn't work, though.

Presumably `Point` has an accessible assignment operator, if the first version works.

---

Just to confirm, now you've pasted the source for `Point`, the copy constructor should look like:

```
Point::Point(const Point &other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
```

(you might as well get comfortable using the initializer list).
The key change is the argument must be a `const` reference: this prohibits accidentally damaging the source object when copying.

Comment: He probably declared a copy constructor but made the argument a `Point&` instead of a `const Point&`

Answer (score 3):

In

```
Line(const Point& p1, const Point& p2): startpoint(p1), endpoint(p2)
```

You are invoking `Point::Point` with `p1` (`p2` respectively) which has type `const Point&`, i.e. you promised never to change the parameters given to `Line::Line`. Now, let's look at your `Point` class. The only method with a matching number of arguments is

```
Point(Point& p);
```

Which takes a `Point&`, something which is okay to modify inside `Point::Point(Point&)`. Thus, you cannot pass `p1` (or `p2`) there because you already promised it would never be changed.

Make your constructor

```
Point(const Point& p);
```

and you can use the initialiser list like you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point(Point& p);
```

Your copy constructor requires a non-`const` reference to a `Point`. This means your can't initialise a point from a `const` reference, which the initialiser list requires. Assignment works because you haven't implemented your own copy-assignment operator, so the implicit one is used.

You should either change the copy constructor to `Point(Point const &);` or, better still, remove it entirely since it does exactly the same as the implicitly-defined one would. Likewise, there's no point in defining your own destructor unless it either needs to do something, or needs to be virtual or non-public.